# Error Kinetic install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I try to install Ros kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 with the next step:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116
sudo apt-get update
```

But when I introuce the last step:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I received the next:

```
E: unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Some idea?

Thank you very much and regards!
Andres.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232596/error-kinetic-install-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [nandezgarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/26671/nandezgarcia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandezgarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/26671/nandezgarcia/) on 2016-04-22**:
I can see that release date is May 2016.
http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions

I suppose that only i can to do wait...

Thanks

Regards, Andres.

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-07-13**:
It is now July....I am having this problem. Linking to new question might be dupe, but in moderation limbo don't want to forget this question exists ;) http://answers.ros.org/question/239491/installing-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-1604-apt-get-update-fail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the OP is a bit confusing: the command is to install Kinetic, but the error message mentions Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1